# How can using Yourkit profiler agent cause program to fail on finding resource bundle

Tags: java, profiler, yourkit

Start my web application running on a linux machine, and go to a webpage works fine,

```
jre/bin/java --add-modules java.xml.bind  --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED -Duser.home=/mnt/disk1/share -Xms150m -Xmx900m -jar lib/songkong-5.9.jar -r
```

but run it with ypagent on the command line so I can profile it from my PC

```
jre/bin/java -agentpath:/mnt/system/config/Apps/YourKit-JavaProfiler-2017.02/bin/linux-armv7-hf/libyjpagent.so --add-modules java.xml.bind  --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED -Duser.home=/mnt/disk1/share -Xms150m -Xmx900m -jar lib/songkong-5.9.jar -r
```

and I get

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key button.hide_help
            at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(Unknown Source)
            at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(Unknown Source)
            at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getString(Unknown Source)
            at com.jthink.songkong.text.TextLabel.getMsg(TextLabel.java:28)
            at com.jthink.songkong.server.page.TabbedPage.hideShowHelpButtons(TabbedPage.java:147)
            at com.jthink.songkong.server.page.TabbedPage.createButtons(TabbedPage.java:82)
            at com.jthink.songkong.server.page.SendSupportFilesPage.createOptions(SendSupportFilesPage.java:126)
            at com.jthink.songkong.server.page.SendSupportFilesPage.createPage(SendSupportFilesPage.java:68)
            at com.jthink.songkong.server.CmdRemote.lambda$configureWebEndPoints$68(CmdRemote.java:177)
            at spark.RouteImpl$1.handle(RouteImpl.java:72)
            at spark.http.matching.Routes.execute(Routes.java:61)
            at spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter.doFilter(MatcherFilter.java:130)
            at spark.embeddedserver.jetty.JettyHandler.doHandle(JettyHandler.java:50)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1568)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:256)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:382)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:708)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:626)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

how can that be (BTW the resource bundle value does exist in resources file)

Answer (score 0):

Version 2017.02 is no longer supported, and it does not support Java 10 and newer.

Please use the latest version YourKit Java Profiler 2018.04 instead.

Comment: HI Im using Java 9, and when I used on earlier version of program it worked fine. I would like to know why it is not working before spending money on a newer version that may exhibit the same problem.